# Bibliography Alphanumeric Numbering

Tags: bibliographies, lists

I would like to learn how it is possible to list bibliographical entries in the form (a), (b), (c) instead of [1], [2], [3] in the references.

Answer (score 1):

The list environment `thebibliography` that LaTeX uses to handle the bibliography and citations is basically a fancy `enumerate` environment. You can change the numbering by changing the format of the relevant counter.

The exact definition of `thebibliography` will depend on the document class you are using and possibly on bibliography/citation-related packages you are loading in your preamble.

The following should work for `article`.

We simply change all `\@arabic\c@enumiv`  to `\@alph\c@enumiv` to switch from Arabic numerals to alphabetic. We then also need to modify `\@bibitem` since that saves the value of the counter and not its current representation to the `.aux` file. Finally we redefine `\@cite` and `\@biblabel` and change the square brackets to round brackets.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{({#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi})}
\def\@biblabel#1{(#1)}

\def\@bibitem#1{%
  \item
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\bibcite{#1}{\csname the\@listctr\endcsname}}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\theenumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@alph\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{sigfridsson}
Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). \enquote{Comparison of methods for
deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments}.
\emph{Journal of Computational Chemistry} 19.4, pp. 377–395.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (a)]

For comparison the original definitions in `latex.ltx` and  `article.cls` were

```
% latex.ltx
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}

\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}

\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

% article.cls
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```